# windows installation error for EFI partition to be NTFS

Tags: windows, dual-boot, uefi

I have on laptop freebsd, fedora, endless and was trying to put windows. But, windows installation fails with error that EFI partition is NTFS and needs to be FAT32. It actually is FAT32. Some search reveals that if EFI partition is removed or marked as non-efi, installation will be successful. But, there is uncertainty if rest of OSes installed will work or not or will boot or not. Also, there are more than 1 EFI partitions. Should marking EFIs partitions as data partitions solve this? Then will it be safe? Please suggest any way to avoid this error.

Answer (score 0):

One EFI system partition (probably as the first partition) is generally enough and  should be marked as such (GUID C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B on GPT partitioned disks). But I can't tell if the change will break your current installations.

You can try:

1. Mark the existing EFI partitions as data partitions. Install Windows and let the installer use unallocated space on the disk. The installer will create an EFI partition for you.
2. When Windows is installed and works, copy/move the content of the other EFI partitions to the new one.
3. In Fedora/FreeBSD, create a new menu entry using `efibootmgr`.

   Example for Fedora, `--part 1` points to the EFI partition:

   ```
   efibootmgr --create --disk /dev/sda --part 1 --loader /EFI/fedora/grubx64.efi --label "Fedora"
   ```
4. Delete the old menu entries using `efibootmgr`:

   ```
   # list entries ordered by number
   efibootmgr
   # delete entry number 7
   efibootmgr --bootnum 7 --delete-bootnum
   ```
5. Delete the old EFI (data) partitions and resize your existing partitions.

Comment: After marking EFO partitions to basic data using fedora live pen drive , installation was successful. But after that OSes are booting properly. It is not clear why those EFI partitions are needed even with their type still basic data.

Comment: The UEFI menu entries point to the wrong EFI partitions and (of course) use those bootloaders. You can modify the entries with `efibootmgr`. See my updated answer.